# Set Material UI card to max height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI Card [as seen here](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/).

I want to set these cards to a maximum height, nicely handling the text and pictures inside.  How would I do this?

Here is some code:

```
 <Card className={classes.card} >
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar aria-label={authorAvatar} src={authorImg} className={classes.avatar}/>
          }
          action={
            <Fieldset className={classes.date}>
              {postDate}
            </Fieldset>
          }
          title={post.title}          
          subheader={
            <Link to={userUrl}>
              {authorName}
            </Link>
          }
        />
        <CardContent>
          <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(bodyHtml)}}></div>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions className={classes.actions} disableActionSpacing>
          <IconButton
            className={classnames(classes.unliked, {
              [classes.liked]: this.state.liked,
            })}
            aria-label="Add to favorites"
            onClick={this.handleFavourite}
          >
```

I am trying to use sizing and maxHeight, but I cannot get the syntax right.

```
import  maxHeight from '@material-ui/system/sizing';

<CardContent maxHeight = "10">
```

This gives several errors.

Do I put it here?

```
const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: 20,
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in the following way:

```
import { sizing }  from '@material-ui/system/';

const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: 20,
    sizing, maxHeight: 300,
  },
```